# PDFKit - PDFPageOverlayViewProvider with PKCanvasView is not forwarding Touch events - WWDC22 Session 10089

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios-pdfkit, pencilkit

I am trying to utilize the `PDFPageOverlayViewProvider` protocol of the `PDFView` class in the `PDFKit` framework introduced with iOS 16 in order to display a `PencilKit` `PKCanvasView` on top of a PDF document so that the user can draw stuff on the PDF.

What I am trying to accomplish is basically the same thing as shown in the [WWDC22 Session 10089](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10089/). Sadly, there is no sample code provided which includes this functionality.

Here is my problem: I manage to add the `PKCanvasView` to the view hierarchy via the `PDFPageOverlayViewProvider` protocol, but I can't draw anything. I debugged the touch events using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56323682/1043495) and it appears that the touches are forwarded to the `PDFDocumentView`, which is an internal subview of the `PDFView` and a parent of my `PKCanvasView`.

[image: View hierarchy from Xcode View debugger]

[image]

How can I make sure that touch events made with the Apple pencil are forwarded to the `PKCanvasView` without disabling the scrolling and panning functionality of the `PDFView`?

Comment: larsschwegmann can you share the sample code that is woking for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution:
put this code in overlayprovider's `pdfView` func:

```
   if (view.documentView != nil){
       for sv in view.documentView!.subviews {
           if (sv.theClassName == "PDFPageView" ){
               sv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
           }
       }
   }
```

For `theClassName` you should extend the `NSObject` like this:

```
extension NSObject {
    var theClassName: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
    }
}
```

Comment: This indeed seems to work, thank you! The NSObject extension is not strictly necessary though ^^

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works, but you can also just set

```
pdfView.isInMarkupMode = true
```

Note that both solutions disable text selection in the PDF while enabling annotation, so you might want to toggle the value when toggling annotation mode, if you need that for your app.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/709054